# Props return empty object in child element

Tags: reactjs

I'm completely new in React and overall in programming.

I need to create an greeting widget which displays greeting for the user based on time of day. User name is retrieved at this point of time from local JSON file.

**This is my parent component (greeting widget):**

```
import React from "react";
import Greeting from "../UserGreeting/Greeting";
import "./greeting-widget.scss";
import database from "../../../db.json";

export const Widget = () => {
  const user = database.userData;

  return (
    <div>
      <div className="clock">This will later be a clock</div>
      <Greeting name={user.userName} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default Widget;
```

**This is my child component**

```
import React from "react";
import "./greeting.scss";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

const Greeting = (props) => {
  console.log(props);

  const greetingText = () => {
    const now = new Date();
    const currentHour = now.getHours();
    if (currentHour >= 4 && currentHour < 12) return "Good Morning";
    else if (currentHour >= 12 && currentHour <= 17) return "Good Afternoon";
    else return "Good Evening";
  };

  return (
    <div className="greeting-wrapper">
      {greetingText()}, {props.name}.
    </div>
  );
};

export default Greeting;

Greeting.propTypes = {
  name: PropTypes.string,
};
```

I do get the proper result in my greeting widget.
[image: Greeting widget result]

**Parent component storybook code:**

```
import React from "react";
import GreetingWidget from "../components/GreetingWidget/GreetingWidget";

export default {
  title: "Components / Greeting Widget",
};

export const Widget = () => {
  return <GreetingWidget />;
};
```

But child component does not display user name, console.log also returns empty object.
[image: Child component result]

**Child component storybook**

```
import React from "react";
import GreetingComponent from "../components/UserGreeting/Greeting";

export default {
  title: "Components / User Greeting",
};

export const Greeting = () => {
  return <GreetingComponent />;
};
```

I don't understand why do I get proper result in my main component but nothing in child component. At first I thought that maybe it's because I'm trying to retrieve information from JSON file, but I've tried to hard code user name in parent component and then pass props to child component. But the same problem still existed. What do I do wrong and what should I do to improve this?

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Have your tried just to test <Greeting name="test" /> and to see in the child that console prints 'test'?

Comment: I've tried. If I print console.log(props.name) it returns undefined. If I print console.log(props) it returns empty object.

Comment: Please share all 4 components codes.

Comment: Other components will not be used in parent component.

Answer (score 1):

try do `props` `destructuring`, then. Instead of receiving it directly as `props` or any `args`, you could **destructure** them to `{{ name }}`:-

However, according to your example above, to me, it seems like your `<Greeting name="user.name"/>` working just find in `Parent component` cause you send name props.
But if you just called the `Child component` (`Greeting`) by **itself**, of course the `props` gonna be **empty**. Since it needs the `name` `props` to be passed by it `parent's component`. That's why I think your `child component` display nothing. if so, then the following fixes will not able to help you then.

#### Fixes 1

- `child component`

```
import React from "react";
import "./greeting.scss";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

const Greeting = ({ name }) => {
  console.log(name);

  const greetingText = () => {
    const now = new Date();
    const currentHour = now.getHours();
    if (currentHour >= 4 && currentHour < 12) return "Good Morning";
    else if (currentHour >= 12 && currentHour <= 17) return "Good Afternoon";
    else return "Good Evening";
  };

  return (
    <div className="greeting-wrapper">
      {greetingText()}, {name}.
    </div>
  );
};

export default Greeting;
```

#### Fixes 2

However, you can just directly import `import database from "../../../db.json";` the **child component** (`Greeting.js`) instead of in the **parent component** (`Widget.js`), like so:-

- `Widget.js` (parent component), don't need to send `props`

```
import React from "react";
import Greeting from "../UserGreeting/Greeting";
import "./greeting-widget.scss";

export const Widget = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <div className="clock">This will later be a clock</div>
      <Greeting />
    </div>
  );
};

export default Widget;
```

- `Greeting.js` (child component), import `import database from "../../../db.json";` here instead:-

```
import React from "react";
import "./greeting.scss";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import database from "../../../db.json";

const Greeting = () => {
  const user = database.userData;

  const greetingText = () => {
    const now = new Date();
    const currentHour = now.getHours();
    if (currentHour >= 4 && currentHour < 12) return "Good Morning";
    else if (currentHour >= 12 && currentHour <= 17) return "Good Afternoon";
    else return "Good Evening";
  };

  return (
    <div className="greeting-wrapper">
      {greetingText()}, {user.name}.
    </div>
  );
};

export default Greeting;
```

#### Fixes 3

You'll need to import `import database from "../../../db.json";` in your `child component storybook` since component `Greeting` needs `props` or `args` to function well. So:-

- `child component storybook`

```
import React from "react";
import GreetingComponent from "../components/UserGreeting/Greeting";
import database from "../../../db.json";

export default {
  title: "Components / User Greeting",
};

export const Greeting = () => {
  const user = database.userData;
  return <GreetingComponent name={user.data} />;
};
```

You can **ignore** **Fixes 1** & **Fixes 2** if you go with **Fixes 3**

Comment: Still get the same problem.

Comment: are you trying to access the `child component` by itself?

Comment: Yes, I've created separate storybook for parent and child components (please see edited post where I've added additional storybook code snippets). Can the problem be in child component storybook code?

Comment: I've tried the second approach you've suggested. It seems to be working fine when props are not sent and database is directly imported into child component.

Comment: Yeah. It will work. Anyhow, I've update my answer above. try **Fixes 3**. I reckoned this will fixed your problems. you don't need **Fixes 1** & **Fixes 2** if you go with **Fixes 3**

Comment: Fixes 3 helped. Seems like the problem was in child component storybook after all. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Try this, i simplified the code in the same file and it seems to work for me.

```
import React from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

const Widget = () => {
  const user = "I am Test User";

  return (
    <div>
      <div className="clock">This will later be a clock</div>
      <Greeting name={user} />
    </div>
  );
};

const Greeting = (props) => {
  console.log(props);

  const greetingText = () => {
    const now = new Date();
    const currentHour = now.getHours();
    if (currentHour >= 4 && currentHour < 12) return "Good Morning";
    else if (currentHour >= 12 && currentHour <= 17) return "Good Afternoon";
    else return "Good Evening";
  };

  return (
    <div className="greeting-wrapper">
      {greetingText()}, {props.name}.
    </div>
  );
};

Greeting.propTypes = {
  name: PropTypes.string,
};

export default Widget;
```